# I cannot create user and email at the same time from Exchange Admin Center

Tags: server, permissions, active-directory, exchange-server

I can create user that exists in Active Directory through the Exchange admin center, but when I try to create a user that is not opened in Active Directory directly through the Exchange admin center, it gives an error like this. This error also occurs when opening resources and shared mailboxes. Is there a solution to this?

I have tried to give "exchange trusted subsystem" permission who is creating the user but that didnt effect anything..

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6VvD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have set "RBAC or Active Directory Split Permissions" on Exchange Server.

You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/permissions/split-permissions/split-permissions?view=exchserver-2019#split-permissions

If you can see and run new-mailbox, new-mailuser....etc cmdlets on Exchange Management Shell (probably ends with insufficient access rights) then you must have set "RBAC Split Permissions" on Exchange Server.

If you even can not see new-mailbox, new-mailuser... etc cmdlets on EMS then you must have set Active Directory Split Permissions.

In AD Split Permissions mode you must create the security principal from AD Management Tools.
From the link one of the changes made when switched to "AD Split Permissions"
"All permissions granted to the Exchange Trusted Subsystem and Exchange servers to create security principals are removed."

Changing Exchange Permission Models will require significant effort and planning.